# Triangle inscribed within a unit circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A triangle $ABC$ is inscribed within the unit circle. Let $x$ be the measure of the angle $C$. Express the length of $AB$ in terms of $x$.

A.) $2\sin x$

B.) $\cos x + \sin x - 1$

C.) $\sqrt{2}(1 - \cos 2x)$

D.) $\sqrt{2}(1 - \sin x)$

I am unsure how to illustrate the circle and calculate the length $x$.

Thank you.
`

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{AB}{\sin x}=2R$$ where $R$ is the circum-radius $=1$

Comment: This solution is based on the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Thanks for enriching the answer

Answer (score 2):

The angle $AOB=2x $, since it intercepts the same arc than the angle $CAB=x $.

thus by the well-known formula

$$AB^2=OA^2+OB^2$$
$$-2OA.OB.\cos (2x) $$
with

$$OA=OB=radius=1$$

hence

$$AB^2=2 (1-\cos (2x)) $$

$$=4\sin^2 (x) $$
and
$$\boxed {AB=2\sin (x) }$$